# How do I fix this error - "Unknown entity "another""

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-intent

Activity that I want to go

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  
    <TextView
         android:text="hi"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="x"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java (has unknown entity error)

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void x(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, another.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an activity go to another activity, but for some reason it doesn't work.
I was expecting it to work, like it should with everyone
Please help it has error "unknown entity" and I don't know why.

Comment: What is the class that you want to go to?

Comment: Change `another` to a class name that extends Activity.

Comment: My class to go is the "another.xml" @TheLibrarian

Comment: But that not another activity. That's a layout.

Comment: Oh so how do I make it go to another layout? @TheLibrarian

Comment: Can you please share your logcat, to get some details of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer # 1

If you want to move to another activity

```
class AnotherActivity extends extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.another);
    }
}
```

you must extend your class "AnotherActivity.class" with "Activity" and override **onCreate** method

#### Answer # 2

```
public void x(View view) {
    setContentView(view)
    // OR
    setContentView(R.layout.another)
}
```

Comment: I have to add another `extends`?

Comment: Yes, to make a class behave like an activity, you must need to extend it

Comment: Answer #2 is the easiest one

Comment: Does it work the same for answer 2 ?

Comment: Ii will only update your layout (xml) which will be showing 'another' screen

Comment: Also answer 1 gives more error

Comment: Actually, you can use answer 1, if u need to manage other activity too

Comment: Answer 2 worked, but it shows "(app) keeps stopping"

Comment: Can you share the logcats

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qBcJKg7L

Comment: its not opening

Comment: Maybe because it's too long?